# Rails 3.1 Upload images and save them to the database and render them back when needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building a Rails Application and i want to store some images to the database and render them back when i need them in the html.erb file.

Can someone point me at the right direction????

Also i have a side bar on my layout file and i want to render something in one controller and then something else in an other controller!

Is that possible?
This is the an exaple layout file but i don't want to render them on the layout

```
<div id="left_sidebar" class="column">

</div>
<div id="main_wrapper" class="column">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
<div id="right_sidebar" class="column">

</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should not store image files in your database. I recommend you use gems like [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

Comment: Nobody would ever use database storage for the kind of purpose this solution covers.
What if I need other services to access the pictures, while these other services can't communicate with the Rails application (in my case, they have access to the MySQL server and nothing else).